# Why does $? -ne 0 work but $? != "0" not work?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to do a simple check if the last expression was successful:

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    chrome a.html
fi
```

and this form works. However, when I try to do:

```
if [ $? != "0" ]; then
    chrome a.html
fi
```

or without the "", it always executes. I'm not sure why this happens, as the following works:

```
if [ $(id -u) != "0" ]; then
#You are not the superuser
echo "You must be superuser to run this" >&2
exit 1
fi
```

I would think $? and $(id -u) both return an integer, and thus the comparison != "0" and -ne 0 should both work. However, it seems $? is not the same type as $(id -u). Any explanation?

Comment: `$?` is exit code of last executed command not the output of `id -u`

Comment: Yes I know, I was just using $(id -u) as comparison because that returns a number as well as $?

Comment: You should surround your variables in " to compensate for variable expansion, otherwise you could run into some problems down the road.

Comment: John's right. All variations in fact do work, I was editing the wrong file when I was trying this! Stupid me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see the behavior you describe:

```
#!/bin/bash
false
echo false returns $?
false
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
        echo 'testing return -ne 0'
fi

false
echo false returns $?
false
if [ $? != "0" ] ; then
        echo 'testing return != "0"'
fi

true
echo true returns $?
true
if [ $? != "0" ] ; then
        echo 'testing return != "0"'
fi
echo done
exit 0
```

yields:

```
false returns 1
testing return -ne 0
false returns 1
testing return != "0"
true returns 0
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because $? returns output as an integer, but $(id -u) returns output as a string, instead of as an integer.  The `-ne` operator is used for number comparison, whereas `!=` is used with string comparisons.  The comparison operator in the shell is not smart enough to automatically convert strings to an integer when you do the comparison using `!=`.